# I can't get access to a recently cloned SSD, because I want to keep my HDD as backup

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, disk-cloning

I cloned my laptop HDD to a NVMe card 240GB, both are recognised in UEFI. At first I disconnected my HDD and it boots successfully from the NVMe card, but then I reconnected the HDD as I want it as a backup device.

I don't want to erase its partitions, when both devices are connected no matter what BIOS boot order is set, it always bootup from the HDD and I can't solve how to boot from the Nvme card. I already modified disk signatures:

[image: disk partitions]

Should I delete my HDD windows partition? If I put Nvme m.2 card as first boot device, a blue screen appears:

[image: blue screen]

Comment: “ Should I delete my HDD windows partition?” - If you do the Windows installation on the SAD won’t be bootable

Comment: `I disconnected my HDD and it boots successfully from the NVMe card` then `If I put SSD as first boot device, a blue screen appears` - so, are there 3 devices? HDD, NVMe and SSD?

Comment: @JaromandaX   only 2 devices , hdd and Nvme card (I call it SSD sometimes), If you look at the image,  F partition contains Windows on Nvme card but below it doesn't read bootable (arranque) as in C: partition